# Filtering files of specific folder using QFileSystemModel and QSortFilterProxyModel subclass

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to filter files of QFileSystemModel using QSortFilterProxyModel. The problem is, I want to only show the contents of a specific folder while filtering. Normally, if I wanted to only show the contents of a specific folder using QFileSystemModel, I would do something like this:

```
view = new QTreeView(this);
fSystemModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);

view->setModel(fSystemModel);

fSystemModel->setRootPath("C:/Qt");
QModelIndex idx = fSystemModel->index("C:/Qt");

view->setRootIndex(idx);
```

But when I use the QSortFilterProxyModel, the index has to be the QSortFilterProxyModel's. Since I could not find much information in [Qt Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) regarding this issue, I looked around and found [this thread](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/15435-QTreeModel-gt-setRootIndex-when-using-QSortFilterProxyModel-segfaults). Using this as a base, I created the following:

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    ui->centralWidget->setLayout(layout);

    view = new QTreeView(this);
    fSystemModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
    filter = new FilterModel();

    filter->setSourceModel(fSystemModel);

    layout->addWidget(view);
    view->setModel(filter);

    fSystemModel->setRootPath("C:/Qt");
    QModelIndex idx = fSystemModel->index("C:/Qt");
    QModelIndex filterIdx = filter->mapFromSource(idx);

    qDebug() << filterIdx.isValid();

    view->setRootIndex(filterIdx);
}
```

**FilterModel.cpp (QSortFilterProxyModel subclass)**

```
#include "filtermodel.h"

bool FilterModel::filterAcceptsRow(int source_row, const QModelIndex &source_parent) const
{
    QModelIndex zIndex = sourceModel()->index(source_row, 0, source_parent);
    QFileSystemModel* fileModel = qobject_cast<QFileSystemModel*>(sourceModel());
    return fileModel->fileName(zIndex).contains("C"); //This line will have custom 
                                                      //filtering behaviour in the future, 
                                                      //instead of the name searching one.
}
```

However, when I run the program, it does not use the specified root index. Moreover, when I use **qDebug()** to see if the **filterIdx** is valid, it prints false. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to see the result of the next line

```
qDebug() << idx << " " << fSystemModel->fileName(idx) << " " << filterIdx.isValid();
```

You can notice that `fSystemModel->fileName(idx)` is `"Qt"` (not full path `"C:/Qt"`). So it doesn't contain `"C"` from your filter (`FilterModel::filterAcceptsRow`).

Comment: I don't see how this explains my problem, since if I use **qDebug() << idx << " " << fSystemModel->filePath(idx) << " " << filterIdx.isValid();**, it shows the full path. Could you clarify a bit more?

Comment: OK, upon looking at my code again I understand what you meant. Still, If I use **return fileModel->filePath(zIndex).contains("C");**, it only moves to the specified folder. How do I filter from there? Apparently, using **&&** or **||** to combine my filter with another will not work, since the filter is applied to the file path as a whole. Is there a workaround to this, or should I try a different approach?

Comment: for example `fileModel->filePath(zIndex) == "C:/Qt" || fileModel->fileName(zIndex).contains("o");` I write `"o"` because Qt-folder has no files contained `"C"` :)

Comment: This was exactly what I was missing! Thank you!